# Is it possible to use standard D3 with React components (and a splash of Redux)?

Tags: d3.js, reactjs, redux

This is a more open-ended question, but I'm wondering if it is possible to combine vanilla/regular JS D3 with React components. I've read a few React-meets-D3 tutorials, but building D3 into React components is just not clicking with my brain for whatever reason. There are great resources available for learning vanilla D3, so I'm wondering if it is possible to inject D3 charts into React components while still taking advantage of data in my Redux store?

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/EcutDavid/D3In20Days d3 with react.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with D3 is it used to change the DOM for normal working.

Here's a good [article with workaround for this problem](https://medium.com/@sxywu/on-d3-react-and-a-little-bit-of-flux-88a226f328f3#.tw96qw7z4). It's a bit messy solution but at the end you'll receive components that works fine with react and you can write native D3 code in them. The key idea is:

> React handle entering and exiting the elements, and D3 handle updating
>   the attributes.

As an example consider this (very simple) area chart that I'm using in my project:

```
const d3Visualization = {

  enter(data) {
    const width = this.props.width;
    const height = this.props.height;

    const x = d3.time.scale.utc().range([0, width]);
    const y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    const xAxis = d3.svg.axis()./* ... axis code */
    const yAxis = d3.svg.axis()./* ... axis code */

    const area = d3.svg.area()
      .x(d => x(new Date(d.dateTime)))
      .y0(height)
      .y1(d => y(d.usage));

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, d => new Date(d.dateTime)));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.usage)]);

    this.d3Path
      .datum(data)
      .transition(100)
      .attr("d", area);

    this.d3XAxis
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    this.d3YAxis
      .call(yAxis)

  }

};

class Area extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    this.d3Node = d3.select(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
    this.d3Path = this.d3Node.select("path.area");
    this.d3XAxis = this.d3Node.select("g.x.axis");
    this.d3YAxis = this.d3Node.select("g.y.axis");

  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    d3Visualization.enter.call(this, this.props.data)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height}>
        <g transform="translate(20,10)">
          <path className="area"/>
          <g className="x axis"></g>
          <g className="y axis">
            <text></text>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    );
  }

}
```

I've simplified the code as much as possible to left only small demo. In the article above you'll find description of most common problems and more complicated demo component as well.